# Any way to reuse a Source[ByteString, Any] (without keeping it all in memory)

Tags: akka-stream, akka-http

Is there any way to make a Source reusable?

I have an akka-http server that receives a large file upload and then streams the (chunked) data to subscriber websockets and other HTTP servers via HTTP POST. In both cases, there is an API that accepts a Source[ByteString, Any]:

- HttpEntity(..., source) in the case of the HTTP POST
- BinaryMessage(source) for the websocket

Using these APIs has some advantages over the versions that take a single ByteString (Only need to do a single HTTP post, can recreate the same chunked message, etc.).

So is there a way to make something like this work (without buffering everything in memory)?

```
val allSinks: Seq[Sink[Source[ByteString, Any], Future[Done]]] = ???

val g = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(allSinks) { implicit builder => sinks =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  // Broadcast with an output for each subscriber
  val broadcast = builder.add(Broadcast[DataSource](sinks.size))
  Source.single(source) ~> broadcast
  sinks.foreach(broadcast ~> _)
  ClosedShape
})
```

Comment: BroadcastHub can provide a reusable source (see https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/stream/stream-dynamic.html). But then the problem seems to be how to determine when the stream has actually completed (since it is a stream of sources).

Answer (score 0):

**Sources are Not Reusable**

Unfortunately a `Source` cannot be reused after it has been exhausted.  The underlying "source" of the data can be re-used to create separate `Source` values but each value can be run on at most one stream.

**Persistence**

If replay capabilities are a requirement then the data being streamed will need to be stored in a persistence mechanism to facilitate replay later.  This mechanism could be a filesystem, database, Kafka,...

Below is a mockup using the filesystem.

The incoming `POST` message body can be streamed to a file in write-mode:

```
post {
  path(Segment) { fileName =>
    extractRequestEntity { entity =>
      complete {
        entity
          .dataBytes
          .toMat(FileIO.toPath(Paths.get(fileName), Set(CREATE_NEW, WRITE)))(Keep.Right)
          .run()
          .andThen {
            case Success(ioResult) =>
              StatusCodes.Ok -> s"wrote ${ioResult.count} bytes"
            case Failure(ex) =>
              StatusCodes.InternalServerError -> ex.toString
          } 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is then no need to create a `Broadcast` hub, you simply respond to `GET` requests with the contents of the file:

```
path(Segment) { fileName =>
  getFromFile(fileName)
}
```

This takes advantage of the fact that most OSes will allow you to write to a file as a stream of bytes while at the same time reading from a file as a stream of bytes...